# Aurelia $parent is undefined on first page load

Tags: aurelia

In Aurelia I currently can't bind to a field from parent (`app.ts`) in landing page.
If I explicitly use `$parent`, I get an exception telling me that `$parent` ist not defined.

If I route to another page and go back to the landing page `$parent` is defined now and I can access fields from parent directly without usage of `$parent` keyword.

I'm sure it word earlier but I think some updated package breaks it. (Didn't recognised it after update)

```
<h1>${testString}</h1><!-- Nothing displayed -->
<h1>${$parent.testString}</h1><!-- ERROR [app-router] TypeError: Cannot read property 'testString' of undefined -->
```

Both dont work initially after page load but after routing back to this page.

What am I missing?

Using aurelia-binding 2.1.5, aurelia-framework 1.3.0, aurelia-router 1.6.3

Comment: How are you creating your element referencing the `app.ts` as `$parent`? Are you using `<compose>` or using a custom element?

Comment: It's just a page opened by the router. There is only `<template>${$parent.testString}</template>` on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using $parent, just use dependency injection to get access to the parent's view-model.

Here's a [GistRun example](https://gist.run/?id=f5e70b0f989696a35b3149110bd88236).

**test-child.html**

```
<template>
  <h1>${app.message}</h1>
</template>
```

**test-child.js**

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {App} from './app';

@inject(App)
export class TestChild {
  constructor(app) {
    this.app = app;
  }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<template>
  <require from="./test-child"></require>
  <test-child></test-child>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```
export class App {
  message = 'Hello World';
}
```